# Custom post type/ Taxonomy User association

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress installation set up with a custom post type called Projects... Projects have categories such as fashion, lifestyle, design, etc.

I would like to make it, so when a user signs up or edits their profile, they can associate themselves with multiple categories in projects.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I know how to create custom user fields but how would I associate fields with the categories?

Comment: Where do you want to achieve this on frontend or admin side?

Comment: Both, I would like users to have the ability to be searched by taxonomy and i'd like to be able to edit them in admin as well.

The thing is I need a project taxonomy search to bring up project posts and user taxonomy search to bring up users that post to that taxonomy so they need to be linked together but they aren't the same thing... not sure if that's common behavior